# Ofuscamento de código em projeto IOS

Tags: ios, ofuscação

Alguém conhece, indica alguma ferramenta parecida com o ProGuard no Android só que pra IOS, para fazer ofuscamento de código em class IOS?

Comment: No SOEN há uma pergunta com resposta e ponderações bem interessantes, se inglês não for problema para você dê uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556849/iphone-ipad-app-code-obfuscation-is-it-possible-worth-it

Comment: https://www.polidea.com/#!heartbeat/blog/Protecting_iOS_Applications Acho que isso pode quebrar seu galho ^^

Answer (score 1):

Já pesquisei isso profissionalmente. Só existem ferramentas pagas para esta função, dentre as quais a Arxan é o fabricante mais conhecido. E são ferramentas bem caras (preço é 5 ou 6 dígitos, em dólar, por plataforma).

Comment: Yes, but in the iOS this is more easy then Android. In Android it is a very problem.